# How to Export Codeigniter 3 Database with bulk insert

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to export the database from [Codeigniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html) the insert query is not bulk.
it crease each row as a new query using `$this->load->dbutil();` and The format agr is

```
   $format = array(
     'ignore' => array($this->ignore_directories),
     'format' => 'zip',
     'filename' => 'db_backup_' . $date . '.sql',
     'add_insert' => TRUE,
     'newline' => "\n"
   );
```

backup Statement

```
$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($format);
```

The problem is that exported data is not in the bulk import format. it simply creates each import as a query which is slow and time-consuming also sometimes it failed to import because PHP time limit.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $db_format=array('format'=>'zip','filename'=>'YOUR DB NAME.sql');
    $backup=& $this->dbutil->backup($db_format);
    $dbname='backup-on-'.date('Y-m-d').'.zip';
    $save='YOUR FOLDER PATH'.$dbname;
    write_file($save,$backup);
    force_download($dbname,$backup);
```

This will help you to export the db in zip file.When you import the extracted file,the db imported fully or bulky.Hope it will helps!!

Comment: this is the same what I mean above its not include insert query bulk or batch

Comment: You want to not include insert query in export file??